# First Derivative at a saddle point

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, derivatives, maxima-minima

Let $f:S\to\mathbb{R}$ be differentiable at $x_0\in S$. Let $x_0$ be a saddle point of $f$ that is there exists $\delta>0$ such that $f(x)\leq f(x_0)$ for all $x\in(x_0,x_0+\delta)$ and $f(x)\geq f(x_0)$ for all $x\in(x_0-\delta,x_0)$. So at one side $x_0$ is a point of maximum and at another side, $x_0$ is a point of minimum of $f$.

I am unable to prove the first derivative $f'(x_0)=0$. I tried in the following way: Let $x=x_0+h$ where $|h|<\delta$, then by the given condition for the right-hand side, we get $f(x_0+h)\leq f(x_0)$ for every $0<h<\delta$. Thus,
$$
\lim_{h\to 0^+}\frac{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)}{h}\leq 0.
$$
Therefore, $f'(x_0)\leq 0$. On the otherhand, by the given condition with the left hand side, we get $f(x_0+h)\geq f(x_0)$ for every $-\delta<h<0$. Thus,
$$
\lim_{h\to 0^-}\frac{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)}{h}\leq 0,
$$
which again gives $f'(x_0)\leq 0$. But to conclude I need to prove that $f'(x_0)\geq 0$.

Can someone please help to proceed. Thanks.

Comment: Show the derivative from the left is $\ge 0$ and from the right it is $\le 0.$

Comment: I have shown from the right $\leq 0$. Can you help how to obtain from the left $\geq 0$?

Comment: It's almost exactly the same argument.

Comment: Can you please inform how. That is what I want to know. Thanks.

Comment: First show us HOW you got that the derivative from the right is $\le 0$.

Comment: I wrote it down above. This is due to the differentiability of $f$, so the right hand derivative is exactly $f'(x_0)$ which is $\leq 0$. But what I found from the left also $\leq 0$. Please see above estimates.

Comment: The top is $\le 0$ and the bottom is $<0.$ What can you say about such a fraction?

Comment: Sorry, but I really do not understand your answer. It would be helpful if you can explain in a more detail to get the nonnegativity of $f'(x_0)$.